# Can I write API endpoints with Truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, api-design

Does anybody knows how to write an API inside a Truffle application?

Answer (score 2):

#### No, Truffle is not a framework for APIs.

It is a wrapper around a `smart-contract` which enables the methods defined in `smart-contract` and makes it available as javascript code.

#### But you can.

Since it is like a node app, you can use any node.js modules to make it work as an API endpoint using `hapi`, `express` etc.

Comment: I tried to add express to truffle but I couldn't, do you know any post or tutorial which can help me?

Comment: Try it the other way round i.e adding web3 and/or pudding to a conventional node project where express is included in the npm project file you will then be able to expose a contract as conventional api.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean API's in the traditional sense then no. However Smart Contracts can be considered as services or APIs in themselves, and that's an increasingly common usage of it. Truffle/Mix/Embark are good frameworks for writing "API's" in that sense.